# Run time error '1004' Paste method of Worksheet class failed (Only on selected computers)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very strange problem with excel vba. I have narrowed the problem down and made this code to represent the problem as simply as possible.

```
   Sub Button1_Click()

   Button1_Click Macro
       Range("A1:B17").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Workbooks.Add
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End Sub
```

On most computers I have no issue, but in the company we have two new laptops that give me the following error message on ActiveSheet.Paste row.

```
Run time error '1004'
Paste method of Worksheet class failed
```

I have tested this on both Windows 10 and 7, and on different computers. Only ones causing problems are the two new ones with Win10.

I saw this thread, and also tried the last option there about adding delays within the code:

[Run Time Error '1004': Paste Method Of worksheet Class Failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770321/run-time-error-1004-paste-method-of-worksheet-class-failed-error)

Any suggestions how to solve this, and/or what is causing this issue?

-Rasmus-

Answer (score 0):

Do avoiding `.Select`.

And while pasting, do clearly determining the destination. Else it might be undefined because of the destination workbook was opened short time before.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

 ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B17").Copy
 Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
 newWB.Worksheets(1).Paste Destination:=newWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the effort. No difference in the outcome. Still hoping for a solution/reason for this.

Comment: @RazMan: Where is the workbook containing the macro stored? Is the `ActiveSheet` from which the range is copied a sheet in the workbook containing the macro? If not, how was it opened before? Sounds as if source sheet and target sheet while copy/paste are in different Excel application instances. Then of course pasting must fail.